# How to use session in nodejs for every random user who visits

Tags: node.js, session

I am creating a nodejs website where people can take online tests .the questions will be taken randomly from a database and displayed for the user to answer .the problems is when another user wants to take the test at the same time , he gets the same randomly genrated questions.how to use session to generate random questions when ever a user wants to take test.

Comment: Your problem does not require a session. You could simply change the question given on every refresh. If you don't want that then you should use sessions but in order to get help we need to know what framework you are using.

Comment: I am using express framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this module: https://github.com/expressjs/session. This is an example setup:

```
var session = require('express-session');

var sessionOpts = session({
    secret: 'yoursecret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
});

app.use(sessionOpts);

app.get('/getQuestion', function(req,res){
    if(req.session.question){
        //show the user the req.session.question
    } else {
        req.session.question = //GENERATE A NEW QUESTION;
        //show the user the new req.session.question
    }
}
```

Comment: its showing some error .. Can u tell me exactly wat u did so i can resolve this..

Comment: added the whole function that outputs the 10 questions INSIDE the router so every time it either generates 10 new random questions or uses the same old ones from the session. The error could be either a typo since I could not test anything without the schema or because the module.exports of totalQuestions is no longer valid.

Comment: you could keep the app.js configuration and try to fix questions.js yourself. You add new data to session using req.session.yourVariable = data; and you can then use the same data by accessing it from the same req object. Since you want new questions generated on request you should have everything inside the get Router.